# Open the most recent file in a shared folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to open the latest file in a shared folder.

I have a code to check the files in a folder of my laptop, like "Downloads" but I have to open a folder in a shared drive and then copy the info of this workbook and paste in another file.

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    
    'Specify the path to the folder
    MyPath = "P:\GTS\zdss\"
    
    'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
    'Get the first Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    
    'If no files were found, exit the sub
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    
        'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        
        'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
        'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        
        'Get the next Excel file from the folder
        MyFile = Dir
        
    Loop
    
    'Open the latest file
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `FileDateTime` must return a correct date even in a Shared location. Did you test what does it return? `Debug.Print LMD`. If it returns as expected, maybe the default date configuration must be checked and adapted...

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ideas. I am not sure whether one will solve your problem but maybe it could help you.

1) I have found this discussion on a forum (http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19669-Workbooks-Open-using-network-path). In my understanding, the problem seems close to your. Maybe try to use the few lines using to manage errors (begin by On Error Resume next).

2) I think you have already verified but the extension of the file is ".xls", not ".xlsx" ?

3) Doing operations on dates in VBA needs particular functions. Here, you are doing a comparison as if it is integers (LMD > LatestDate). Moreover, I am not sure that LatestDate will have a proper value, because you never define it in the beginning. I suggest to change the code in this way. First define LatestDate before the While statement with an arbitrary low value (so, you are sure that the variable has a value and the If LMD > LatestDate statement will work properly).

```
LatestDate = Format("01.01.1900", "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Second, change the If LMD > LatestDate statement :

```
If DateDiff("d",LatestDate,LMD) > 0 Then
```

Of course, you need to change the parameter "d" (for day) in case you want a comparison in other unit.

Cheers.